# int division rounding library?

Tags: c++, c, math, int, integer-division

Does anyone know of an open-source C or C++ library with functions implementing every integer division mode one might want?  Possible behaviors (for positive result):

```
round_down, round_up,
round_to_nearest_with_ties_rounding_up,
round_to_nearest_with_ties_rounding_down,
round_to_nearest_with_ties_rounding_to_even,
round_to_nearest_with_ties_rounding_to_odd
```

with each (aside from round-to-even and round-to-odd) having two variants

```
// (round relative to 0; -divide(-x, y) == divide(x, y))
negative_mirrors_positive,
// (round relative to -Infinity; divide(x + C*y, y) == divide(x, y) + C)
negative_continuous_with_positive
```

.

I know how to write it, but surely someone has done so already?

As an example, if we assume (as is common and is mandated in C++11) that built-in signed integral division rounds towards zero, and that built-in modulus is consistent with this, then

```
int divide_rounding_up_with_negative_mirroring_positive(int dividend, int divisor) {
  // div+mod is often a single machine instruction.
  const int quotient = dividend / divisor;
  const int remainder = dividend % divisor;
  // this ?:'s condition equals whether quotient is positive,
  // but we compute it without depending on quotient for speed
  // (instruction-level parallelism with the divide).
  const int adjustment = (((dividend < 0) == (divisor < 0)) ? 1 : -1);
  if(remainder != 0) {
    return quotient + adjustment;
  }
  else {
    return quotient;
  }
}
```

Bonus points: work for multiple argument types; fast; optionally return modulus as well; do not overflow for any argument values (except division by zero and MIN_INT/-1, of course).

If I don't find such a library, I'll write one in C++11, release it, and link to it in an answer here.

Comment: There's a few in C++11 and more in Boost. I don't recall the extents of those, though.

Comment: there is probably no library since you can get normal rounding behavior by adding 0.5 and casting to int

Comment: @technosaurus, `std::round` does that, too.

Comment: Why would you want this? its not that hard to do in-line: round = (int)(<number>+0.5), round_down = (int)number etc etc.

Comment: I belive there are functions for most of that on `<math.h>`, like `ceil()` and `floor()`

Comment: Where is it in std or Boost? There's plenty for floating point.  But `double` has less precision than int64, and floating-point is completely unsuitable for some platforms.  This is for scientific software where a chance of being imprecise in a way different from specification is unacceptable.  (True, it just might be possible to write something correct and performant with x87 `long double` with C99 IEEE754 fesetround() etc. That sounds far harder to write and to prove correct than writing this lib with twos-complement ints, for reasons that do not fit in this margin.)

Comment: About those variants: `round_down` + `negative_mirrors_positive` == `round_towards_zero`.  The other combinations give: towards-positive-infinity, towards-negative-infinity, and away-from-zero.  Use those instead of "up," "down," and the variants.

Comment: I really don't get people saying there's no need for this since the implementations are one-liners. A quarter of everything in the standard library is one-liners... the point is to say what you want to happen rather than to have to type up the implementation and introduce magic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I wrote something.  The implementation is typically ugly template and bitwise code, but it works well.  Usage:

```
divide(dividend, divisor, rounding_strategy<...>())
```

where  `rounding_strategy<round_up, negative_mirrors_positive>` is an example strategy; see list of variants in my question or in the source code. https://github.com/idupree/Lasercake/blob/ee2ce96d33cad10d376c6c5feb34805ab44862ac/data_structures/numbers.hpp#L80

depending only on C++11 [*], with unit tests (using Boost Test framework) starting at https://github.com/idupree/Lasercake/blob/ee2ce96d33cad10d376c6c5feb34805ab44862ac/tests/misc_utils_tests.cpp#L38

It is polymorphic, decent speed, and does not overflow, but doesn't currently return modulus.

[*] (and on boost::make_signed and boost::enable_if_c, which are trivial to replace with std::make_signed and std::enable_if, and on our caller_error_if() which can be replaced with assert() or if(..){throw ..} or deleted.  You can ignore and delete the rest of the file assuming you're not interested in the other things there.)

Each divide_impl's code can be adapted to C by replacing each T with e.g. int and T(CONSTANT) with CONSTANT.  In the case of the round_to_nearest_* variant, you'd either want to make the rounding kind be a runtime argument or create six copies of the code (one for each distinct rounding variation it handles).  The code relies on '/' rounding towards zero, which is common and also specified by C11 (std draft N1570 6.5.5.6) as well as C++11.  For C89/C++98 compatibility, it could use stdlib.h div()/ldiv() which are guaranteed to round towards zero (see http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/div.3.php , http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div )